# Pulling out a distribution ? $u\circ f$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, differential-operators

In an attempt to generalize solutions with discontinuities to a PDE, we want to consider distributions.

We have a continuous function $g\in C(Y)$ and a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow Y,\ f$ is $C^\infty$ , we want to generalize the classical continuous function $g\circ f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to a distribution.

We are able to generalize $g$ as a distribution $u\in \mathscr{D}'(Y)$ but we want a distribution $U\in \mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ that generalize $g\circ f$ , by pulling back : $U= u\circ f$ .

I don't quite understand how am I allowed to do that ? Here is what I tried :

If $\phi$ is a test function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ then we can map it to the test function $T(\phi)$ on $Y$ that is defined by $$T(\phi) (y)= \int_{f^{-1}\big(\{y\}\big)}\phi(x)dx \quad, \text{ for all } y\in Y$$

Here $T$ is a well defined operator. Is this a well known construction ? 
Then we can consider $U(\phi)= u(T(\phi))= u\circ T(\phi)$ .

But does $U$ generelize $g\circ f$ ?

Attendum : 
The space $Y$ is the real line $\mathbb{R}$ and my $f$ is not even injective, $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is rather a projection and has the form $f(x)= x\cdot v$ where $v$ is a fixed vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ .

Comment: This is well known for certain $f$, including the case when $f$ is a diffeomorphism. In any case, the motivation is always to assume $g$ is a test function, and manipulate $\int (g \circ f)\phi\,dx$ so that it involves $g$ instead of $g \circ f$, so that the resulting expression makes sense even when $g$ is a general distribution.

Comment: @NotaChoice: Your operator $T$ is plagued by many problems. First, if $f$ is a diffeomorphism (or, more generally, $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ has measure $0$ for all $y$) then the integral defining $T(\varphi)(y)$ is $0$ for all $y$. But let us say that the measure $\mathrm d x$ that you use is some intrinsic measure on $f^{-1}(\{y\})$. Second, how do you know that $T(\varphi)$ has compact support, in order to be a test function?

Comment: I am beginning to realize it is not going to work, my $f$ is not injective, let me append more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of strategy, try to define the object that you are looking for, take note of where your approach fails and correct it in these places.

If $u \in \mathcal D'(Y)$ and $f : X \to Y$ is smooth between smooth manifolds, you would like to somehow obtain $u \circ f \in \mathcal D' (X)$. Let $\varphi \in \mathcal D (X)$ be a test function. No matter how you defined $u \circ f$, you would clearly want it to have the reasonable property that $\langle u \circ f, \varphi \rangle = \langle u, (\varphi \circ f^{-1}) \, |\det (\mathrm d f)^{-1}| \rangle$, because you want to recover the usual change of variable formula when $u$ is an integrable function. This shows that $f$ must be a diffeomorphism, otherwise there is nothing left for you to do. Next, you encounter another problem: while it is true that $(\varphi \circ f^{-1}) \, |\det (\mathrm d f)^{-1}|$ is smooth on $Y$, nobody guarantees that is has compact support. You can fix this in only two ways:

- either require $u$ to be a compactly supported distribution (because the test functions for these need not be compactly-supported);
- or require $f$ to be a [proper map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map).

In any case, the requirement that $f$ be a diffeomorphism massively restricts who $Y$ can be. This shows that the pull-back is not a very interesting operation on distributions.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is $(\phi\circ f^{-1}) |\det(df)^{-1}|$ ? I am reading $u$ acts on the function $\phi\circ f^{-1}$ but multiplied by the absolute value $|\frac{1}{\det(df)}|$ where $d f$ is the differential form of $f$ ?

Comment: @NotaChoice: Exactly. Since $f$ is a diffeomorphism, $\mathrm d f$ is never zero, therefore $\det \mathrm d f$ has constant sign, so its modulus is smooth, so the product with $\varphi \circ f^{-1}$ is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple formula for the case where the distribution $g$ is of finite order and $f$ is a diffeomorphism.  The first condition means that $f$ has the form $D^nG$ (distributional derivative) for a continuous $G$ and integer $n$.  The required distribution is then $\left(\frac 1{f‘}D\right)^n (G\circ f)$.  This suffices for most practical situations, e.g., where $g$ is the Dirac distribution, and can be generalised to more general ones using standard localisation methods („recollement des morceaux“).

Comment: What does $‘$ in $f‘$ mean?

Comment: What it usually means— the derivative.

Comment: In this case, it was probably supposed to be $'$ or $\prime$, but not $‘$. Anyway, what do you mean by $\frac 1 {f'}$ for a diffeomorphism $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$? Also, who is the operator $D$ in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Since $f$ is a diffeomorphism, $f´$ has no zeros so its reciprocal is a smooth function. The distributional derivative  $D$ and hence $\frac 1 {fˋ}D$  is an operator on the space of distributions and so can iterated as often as you want.

Comment: The inverted question mark instead of a prime seems to be a bug—it is not what I typed and attempts to correct it have been fruitless.

Comment: It seems to me that you write $\mathbb R^n$ but in reality you think of $\mathbb R$. It is clear who $D$ is on $\mathbb R$, but I do not see who it is on $\mathbb R^n$. In fact, I believe that your answer is not true in $\mathbb R^n$ without some serious reformulation.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was starting with the simple one dimensional case which is interesting enough and is where most people start.  The same elementary  method works in higher dimensions but the use of Jacobi matrices and multi-indices makes its exposition on this forum impractical.  If the OP displays any interest, I would be happy to supply references.